# Ordering by a field, only if it exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get all users, and order them by a field on another table, however this field doesn't always exist?

Users - Holds Users
User Meta - Holds metadata, specifically "weight" which is what I'm trying to order by.

A more concrete solution would be to automatically define them a default weight, however is there anyway I can make it work without? Current working query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users u, usermeta um 
WHERE u.ID = um.ID 
  AND u.name LIKE '%search_terms%';
```

Lost on the order by part, any/all help would be appreciated!

Comment: you can use this : `order by IFNULL(um.weight,0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a key relationship between the tables (`u.ID = um.ID`) and you want to list all users, you could use something like this to order by `weight` on `usermeta`.

The `LEFT JOIN` lets you keep ALL users, regardless of their existence in `usermeta`:

```
SELECT *, IFNULL(um.weight,9999) as newweight
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN usermeta um on u.ID = um.ID
WHERE u.name LIKE '%search_terms%'
ORDER BY IFNULL(um.weight,9999);
```

Comment: If your field is `NOT NULL`, but you want to do the same thing with zero instead of NULL, you can replace `IFNULL(um.weight,9999)` with `IF(um.weight, um.weight, 9999)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL's IFNULL to define a default value for weight

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM users u, usermeta um 
WHERE u.ID = um.ID AND                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      u.name LIKE '%search_terms%'
ORDER BY  
      CASE WHEN um.weight IS NULL THEN 9999 ELSE um.weight END;
```

You can use a case statement to react to a missing `weight` by substituting it for something else if it is missing.