# MySQL ORDER BY field only if field exists

Tags: php, mysql

In MySQL I want to sort by a field if that field exists as a column in the table.  If that field does not exist I want the query to ignore that segment of the query.  If I try something like

```
SELECT
    post.*
FROM post AS post
WHERE post.postid IN (9818,9814,9815)
ORDER BY IFNULL(post.vote_count,0) > 5 DESC;
```

at the end of my query I get the error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'post.vote_count' in 'order clause'
```

The table structure for post has postid, threadid, and title fields.  How should I write this query?

(I've seen [Ordering by a field, only if it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588854/ordering-by-a-field-only-if-it-exists).  That answer doesn't work for me since I can't add the earlier portion of the query, "IFNULL(post.vote_count,0) as newvotecount".)

Comment: Please add your table structure and the complete query

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL for this (`prepare` and `execute`).

Comment: @juergend, let me know if how I have edited the question helps.

Comment: But you have no `vote_count` column in your table. What do you expect the DB to do with that?

Comment: I expect the query to skip the ORDER by element of the query.

Comment: Again - you have no `vote_count` column in your table! Please add example data and expected output.

Comment: The fact that I don't have vote_count column in my table is irrelevant.
SELECT
    post.*
FROM post AS post
WHERE post.postid IN (9818,9814,9815)

works.

Comment: Irrelevant? Hardly. This kind of problem typically points to more serious problems about the design of your schema. You should know what columns exist in your tables.

Answer (score -2):

You can not use field in query if it is not exists in table (or as alias in query)

Comment: That Possible using exist

Comment: Exist can be used to see if another recordset exists. Not column.

Comment: Kindly check my answer to this post

Comment: Yes, you could check column existance in query, thats true. But you still cant use not existent column in a query

Answer (score -2):

In Oracle u can do this by using following

```
    SELECT * FROM table_name
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN EXISTS (select 1
                              FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
                              WHERE lower(column_name) IN lower('column1_name') AND lower(table_name) = lower('table_name')) THEN column1_name
                   ELSE column2_name
                   END;
```

Same way u replace the Oracle System table with Mysql System Table

---

For Mysql :

```
    SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('columnA','ColumnB')

    AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase';
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them)

Comment: wat issue u r facing?

Comment: If the column name doesn't exist you will get an error to the effect that `column2_name` does not exist.